# Using global entry when ticket has only middle initial, not middle name

Tags: air-travel, usa, customs-and-immigration, global-entry

Will having your middle initial on your ticket rather than middle name that is on your passport affect the use of global entry when coming into the US?

Comment: AFAIK you don't even show your ticket for Global Entry.

Comment: You don't show your ticket to anyone, but the system needs to identify the flight you arrived on. I imagine it can cope with small naming differences though since you will have been identified via APIS with passport number and DoB

Answer (score 7):

Global Entry is not related to the ticket you used, and nobody wants to see your ticket after arrival.

It needs to match your *passport*, but US CBP makes sure of that when they create the card.

Answer (score 2):

Since I stopped using my passport at Global Entry machines and began using a green card instead, the machines have (sometimes?) started asking me to confirm the flight I will be/was on against the record they apparently get from the airline, so they clearly have some interest in the flight. Since I still use the passport for check-in but use a different document at the machine, a guess might be that they don't ask about the flight when the document matches the flight record but may ask for confirmation when they don't and they found the flight record by a name/birthday match instead. Or something.

Regardless of the reason, however, it is the case that while I have a middle name in my passport I have never included that (full) name on a ticket; I have very occasionally ended up with my middle initial on a ticket when I paid with a credit card having that initial in the name. Neither the Global Entry machines nor anything else has ever cared, and when it has offered a flight record for confirmation it has always been mine.